# Why are uncertainties calculated as an average?

Tags: average, error-propagation

Imagine there is a cube with length $l = (10 \pm 0.2) \; \text{cm}$. The volume $V$ would be $l^3 = 1000 \; \text{cm}^3$ and the uncertainty in $V$, $\Delta V$ would be $\frac{10.2^3 - 9.8^3}{2} = 60.008 \; \text{cm}^3$. I would then write $V = (1000 \pm 60.008) \; \text {cm}^3$.

Now, calculating the *forward* uncertainty $\Delta V_f$ and *backward* uncertainty $\Delta V_b$ yields the following:
$$\Delta V_f = 10.2^3 - 10^3 = 61.208 \; \text{cm}^3$$
$$\Delta V_b = 10^3 - 9.8^3 = 58.808 \; \text{cm}^3$$

Hence, isn't $V = (1000 \pm 60.008) \; \text {cm}^3$ **not** a true representation of reality since the maximum value of $V$ is $(1000 + 61.208) \; \text{cm}^3$ and not $(1000 + 60.008) \; \text{cm}^3$? Shouldn't the notation for uncertainty be something like $(1000 \pm (61.208, 58.808)) \; \text{cm}^3$ instead? Wouldn't the discrepancy be extremely large for $\Delta V_f >>> \Delta V$?

Comment: Normally you have good enough underlying measurements that your "$\Delta V$" is so much smaller than your "$V$" that the forward and backward uncertainties are quite close, and in particular can be well approximated by $V'(l) \Delta l$ which in your case is $3l^2 \Delta l=60$. Of course this assumes that the quantity whose uncertainty you're trying to propagate is a differentiable function of the quantities you measured.

Comment: This plays in particularly nicely with the "physicist" way of propagating uncertainties, which is based on modeling errors in terms of independent Gaussians with means much larger than the standard deviations. This is to be contrasted with the "interval arithmetic" way of propagating uncertainties, which should indeed be done the way you described, keeping track of any asymmetries as you go.

Comment: I personally wouldn't divide by two; if you're looking for practical use just be aware of the upper and lower bounds for $V$. Knowing the range of $V$ and the size of this range is relevant, since the statement $V=1000\pm 60.008$ is just incorrect

Comment: Okay, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have a cube whose edge length is $(10 \pm 0.2)\ \mathrm{cm}.$
Did you actually mean to say that the edge length can be anywhere
between $9.8$ cm *exactly* and $10.2$ cm *exactly*?
That is, it is possible that the length is $9.80001$ cm or $10.19999$ cm,
but it is absolutely *impossible* that the length is $9.79999$ cm
or $10.20001$ cm?

If that is what you meant, then it may indeed make sense to say that the volume is strictly bounded by $941.142 < V < 1061.208.$
That is how we mathematically interpret the information that
$9.8 < \ell < 10.2$ and $V = \ell^3.$

However, the notation $\ell = 10 \pm 0.2$ is not generally used in mathematics
to signify that $9.8 < \ell < 10.2.$
Instead, if you want a compact notation for use in an exact mathematical context
that signifies that $9.8 < \ell < 10.2,$
try $\lvert \ell - 10 \rvert < 0.2.$

In most mathematical contexts, for example when solving a quadratic equation,
$\ell = 10 \pm 0.2$ signifies that either $\ell = 9.8$ or $\ell = 10.2,$
and that $\ell$ is not any other value in between those two possibilities.

The people who write $\ell = (10 \pm 0.2)\ \mathrm{cm}$ to signify that
$\ell$ is "approximately $10$ cm but possibly up to $0.2$ cm larger or smaller"
are physicists, chemists, engineers, and other practical people.
Those same people also usually keep track of the *significant digits*
in their calculations, and in $10 \pm 0.2$ you have only three significant digits
(if even that many; really it should be written $10.0 \pm 0.2$).
Hence, from the point of view of the kind of person *who normally would write*
$\ell = (10.0 \pm 0.2)\ \mathrm{cm}$ to express uncertainty among more than two possible exact values,
the correct answer is that $V = (1000 \pm 60)\ \mathrm{cm}^3,$
or more explicitly $V = (1.00 \pm 0.06)\times 10^3\ \mathrm{cm}^3.$

Such people *do* sometimes recognize different error bounds above and below the nominal value, however.
For example, if $\ell = (10.0 \pm 0.5)\ \mathrm{cm},$ then
$V = \left( 1.00 \begin{matrix}\scriptsize{}+0.16 \\[-1ex]
      \scriptsize{}-0.14\end{matrix}\right) \times 10^3\ \mathrm{cm}^3.$
If your application is such that you are writing things like $10.0 \pm 0.2$
to signify a range of uncertainty and you need to propagate an asymmetric range,
you could adopt that notation.
Note that in the notation $1.00 \begin{matrix}\scriptsize{}+0.16 \\[-1ex]
      \scriptsize{}-0.14\end{matrix}$
it is very clear which number is added for the upper bound and which is subtracted for the lower bound, unlike in the notation $1000 \pm (61.208, 58.808).$

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered (in the comments). I am writing this so that this question no longer remains in the unanswered section.

Here is a brief summary of the answer (from the comments):

- Yes, $V = (1000 \pm 60.008) \; \text{cm}^3$ is **not** a true representation of reality. $V = (1000 \pm (61.208, 58.808)) \; \text{cm}^3$ is more precise.
- Using $\Delta V$ as $60.008 \; \text{cm}^3$ usually stems from the "physicist" point of view, in contrast to the "interval arithmetic" approach which keeps track of any asymmetries.
- Generally $\Delta V$ is so tiny such that $\Delta V_f - \Delta V_b \approx 0$. In this case, $\Delta V$ can be well approximated by $V^{\prime}(l)\cdot \Delta l$, assuming that $V(l)$ is differentiable.
- Avoiding dividing by $2$ in $\frac{10.2^3 - 9.8^3}{2}$ can be more useful since it can give a better understanding of the range in a practical setting.

Credits: [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian), [FShrike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/815585/idiotic-shrike)

Comment: And since my name is on this answer, I may as well add that I am no statistician - I'm sure there are many situations where dividing out by two has a purpose; it just completely depends on your definition of uncertainty, and if you're getting confused then a clearer picture of the range of values $V$ could take on is important

Comment: Just to clarify, the "physicist" answer for the uncertainty of your $V$ would be $3l^2 \Delta l = 60$, not $60.008$. The point of that remark was that the physicist way of doing things inherently keeps the uncertainty symmetric.

Comment: @Ian Yes, in fact, I had asked a question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4207423/905694) exactly about that where I ignorantly used the "physicist" approach!